# Loading result of a useState Array

Tags: reactjs

I have a `useState` initialized with default value.

I'm trying to loop through it and display a list of cards.
If i try to add a card manually it works, but using `map` or `foreach` doesn't seem to loop through the initial list

```
function App() {
  const [raffles, setRaffles] = useState<Raffle[]>([new Raffle("Raffle 1")])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {
        raffles.map(raffle => {
          <RaffleCard 
            name = {raffle.name}
            callback = {joinRaffle} />
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

class Raffle {
  name: string

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name
  }
}
```

Comment: Without seen the RaffleCard component is difficult to determine what is going on.  Are you sure it is not looping? or maybe the RaffleCard is not rendering properly?

Comment: You have neglected to return the mapped component from the callback. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forgetting to return the JSX in your mapping function.

```
function App() {
  const [raffles, setRaffles] = useState<Raffle[]>([new Raffle("Raffle 1")])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {
        raffles.map((raffle, index) => {
          return <RaffleCard key={index}
            name = {raffle.name}
            callback = {joinRaffle} />
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

class Raffle {
  name: string

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name
  }
}
```

Also, the `map` function gives you access to the index of the array you're iterating. React might complain if you dont assign a key to your JSX elements. Add `key={index}` to each `Raffle` element.